# Updating/inserting values via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I don't know if this right or not, but is it safe to update/insert lots of record to mysql by an ajax call? I have a bootstrap modal with some 200 student's names and 200 checkboxes representing their attendance. The worst case is ticking the 200 checkboxes. The update process has some where clauses as well(date, semester, department).
So, is it okay to do this via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing bad to do that, you can send that you want to your server by client side. 
However you need to be careful about data that you receive on server side and do some tests which valid data because it's easy to handle and send malicious data.